# VS2010 Solutions Always Opening with VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I just installed VS2010 via the web installer on a Win7 machine that already had 2008.  Everytime I open a 2010 sln file it launches 2008 and errors saying the solution was created with a newer version.  I can do an "Open With..." and choose 2010 or the 2010 version selector, but the option to "Always Open With" is grayed out.  I went into Control Panel > File Associations and the option is grayed out there too.

How the heck can I get my machine to launch 2010 for 2010 solutions??

Comment: is is this really related to programming or just windows?

Comment: I don't know - I questioned whether to post it, but it seems unique to VS.  My other file extensions are not "locked" like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following to fix my problem: Go into VS 2010 and click "Tools", Options, Environment, General, "Restore File Associations"

I tried this option first without any success:
1. Go to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe"
2. Set Properties->Compatibility->Run this program as an administrator.

Comment: I'm a bad Stack Overflow user! I found this solution a little while after I posted, and it mostly did the trick for me, but I never posted it here. I do still occasionally run into a solution that doesn't work right - usually won't open at all by double-click. Not sure what that is, I haven't dug in as it has mostly been open source stuff I am referencing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Vista or Windows 7? If I recall correctly, there is an option in the start menu called "Default Programs". Go there, find the SLN extension, and pick VS2010 to open it. This should set the default program for you without any more prompting.

Comment: Thanks Bill.  It's Win7 and I updated the question to show that.  Unfortunately, the Default Programs/File Association dialog shows that grayed out checkbox, so I can't permanently associate SLN files to anything!  That's the frustrating part.